distance between a vector to a subspace problem
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $V_{1}\subset V_{2}\subset H$ be two finite dimensional subspace where inclusion is strict. Let $x\in H$ be a vector such that $x\notin V_{1}$ and $x\notin V_{2}$. Consider the distance between $x$ and these two subspace, $dist(x,V_{1})$ and $dist(x,V_{2})$. It is clear that $dist(x, V_{1})\geq dist(x, V_{2})$. My question is, what are the conditions that two distances are equal?

One sufficient condition is $V_1=V_2$.

In this situation, $V_{1}$ is strictly contain in $V_{2}$.

I guess one condition would be that $V_2\setminus V_1$ is orthogonal to $x$.

The equality holds iff $x\in V_1\oplus V_2^\perp$. Note that if there are $u\in V_2^\perp$, $v\in V_2\cap V_1^\perp$, and $w\in V_1$ such that $x=u+v+w$, then $\operatorname{dist}(x, V_2)=\lVert u\rVert$, and $\operatorname{dist}(x,V_1)=\lVert u+v\rVert$. By the definition of inner-product-induced norm and $u\perp v$, $\lVert u+v\rVert^2=\lVert u\rVert ^2+\lVert v\rVert^2$, so the equality holds iff $v=0$ iff $x\in V_1\oplus V_2^\perp$.
Now we are left with the goals

$H=V_2\oplus V_2^\perp$: let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ be an orthogonal basis of $V_2$. Then, for any $x\in H$, $$x=\underbrace{\frac{\langle x, e_1\rangle}{\langle e_1,e_1\rangle}e_1+\cdots+\frac{\langle x, e_n\rangle}{\langle e_n,e_n\rangle}e_n}_{\in V_2}+\underbrace{\left(x-\left(\frac{\langle x, e_1\rangle}{\langle e_1,e_1\rangle}e_1+\cdots+\frac{\langle x, e_n\rangle}{\langle e_n,e_n\rangle}e_n\right)\right)}_{\in V_2^\perp}$$
If $x=v+v^\perp$ where $v\in V$ and $v^\perp\in V^\perp$, then $\operatorname{dist}(x, V)=\lVert v^\perp\rVert$: let $u\in V$ be arbitary. Then $\lVert x-u\rVert^2=\lVert v^\perp +v-u\rVert^2=\lVert v^\perp\rVert^2+\lVert v-u\rVert^2\geqslant \lVert v^\perp\rVert^2$.

